# How can i iterate Arraylist of an object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist, iterator, display

I have a arrayList of an object , and i cannot iterate my list forward or reward , i  don't want to display my message in these case but it does .

```kotlin
private fun handleLivePopUp() { // vous êtes en direct
       val id =  presenter.programItems?.indexOf(presenter.currentProgram)
        // val it =         presenter.programItems?.listIterator()
       // val previous = if (id == 0) presenter.programItems!!.size - 1 else id?.minus(1)

       if (id != null){

           if(id == 0){ //si liste == +1 ou liste == -1 on affiche pas
               binding.playerController.startOverImg.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_startover))
               binding.playerController.startOverToast.visibility = View.GONE
               binding.playerController.startOverLiveToast.visibility = View.VISIBLE
               // presenter.programItems!!.size - 1

           } else if(id == id - 1 || id == id + 1){
               binding.playerController.startOverImg.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_startover))
               binding.playerController.startOverLiveToast.visibility = View.GONE  // apparait visible à chaque swipe
               binding.playerController.startOverToast.visibility = View.GONE

           }
       }
```

This is the code i'm trying to do

Comment: There is no attempt at iterating anything in this code. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What list?  What iterator?

Comment: Sorry , it's not a list , i don't want to display message , if i go to the next index.